# Pine Script: Is there a way to only consider specific hours of the day when calculating averages?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

For example: I'm using the following code to calculate the average daily volume of the past 7 days:

```
isess = session.regular
t = ticker.new(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker, session=isess)
AvgVol7 = ta.sma(volume, 7)
SecAvgVol7 = request.security(t, 'D', AvgVol7[1], gaps=barmerge.gaps_off , lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

But what I would like to do is to calculate the same average daily volume of the past 7 days, but only consider hours from 6am to 6pm. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can use pine arrays: push/accumulate the volume of bars from needed interval, pop front older values and use array.avg() for calculate average

Comment: @AndreyD thanks a lot! I thought arrays should be able to achieve this, but I'm still learning how they work, do you by any chance know any other script on tradingview that uses something like this that I could refer to?

Answer (score 1):

```
//@version=5
indicator("Custom Range Daily Volume", overlay = false)

start_hr = input.int(6, title = "Start hour")
end_hr = input.int(18, title = "End hour")

num_days = input.int(7, title = "Number of days")

var float[] daily_volumes = array.new_float()

var float todays_volume = 0.0

new_day = ta.change(time("D")) != 0

eod_time_close = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", time_close, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

in_time_range = hour >= start_hr and hour < end_hr
is_eod = time_close == eod_time_close and barstate.isconfirmed

if new_day
    todays_volume := 0.0
else if in_time_range
    todays_volume += volume

if is_eod
    array.unshift(daily_volumes, todays_volume)
    if array.size(daily_volumes) > num_days
        array.pop(daily_volumes)

float daily_avg_vol = na
float repainting_avg_vol = na

if array.size(daily_volumes) == num_days
    daily_avg_vol := array.avg(daily_volumes)
    repainting_avg_vol := in_time_range ? (array.sum(daily_volumes) - array.get(daily_volumes, num_days - 1) + todays_volume) / num_days : na
plot(daily_avg_vol)
plot(fixnan(repainting_avg_vol), color = in_time_range ? color.yellow : color.gray, style = plot.style_circles)
```